# If $Q$ is Idempotent, prove that $R(Q)$ is closed and $||Q|| \geq 1$ if $Q \neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space, an operator $Q \in B(H)$ is said to be idempotent if $Q^2=Q$ for all $x \in H$. (B(H) is the vector space of bounded operators on $H$).

If $Q$ is Idempotent, prove that $R(Q)$ is closed and $||Q|| \geq 1$ if $Q \neq 0$

Here $R(Q)$ is the range of $Q$ and $||Q||=sup_{x \in H} \{Q(x) : x \in H\}$

---

So I have already shown that $Q$ is idempotent $iff$ $Q(y)=y$ for all $y \in R(Q)$...

This is one of the problems I've been trying to figure out for a week and can't make any real progress... I knwo there are a lot of geoemtric properties inherent in a Hilbert space that I've been trying to work with but I just can't seem to figure it out... Help greatly appreciated >.< Thank you so much

Comment: I believe it should be $\Vert Q(x)\Vert$ in the definition of $\Vert Q\Vert$. If I am correct, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relating to your note: $R(Q)=\{y\in H:y=Q(y)\}$ since $Q$ is idempotent.

To show $R(Q)$ is closed, take a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ in $R(Q)$ which converges to some $y\in H$, and we want to show that $y\in R(Q)$. By the above note, $x_n=Q(x_n)$ for each $n\geq 1$. Now use continuity of $Q$ since it is bounded.

Now to show that $\Vert Q\Vert\geq 1$ when $Q\neq 0$, first note that $R(Q)\neq\{0\}$. Thus, there exists some $0\neq y\in R(Q)$, so we can let $\hat y:=\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert}$ which has norm $1$. What can we say about $\Vert Q(\hat y)\Vert$ and what does this tell us about $\Vert Q\Vert$?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly still... We can say that $||Q(\bar{y})|| = \frac{1}{||y||}||Q(y)||... ? I'm missing the final piece >.<

Comment: Hint: $y\in R(Q)$.

Comment: Ooh $y \in R(Q)$ so $||Q(\bar{y})|| = \bar{y}$  got it thanks man